# Saving the order in which user clicks on rows of a HTML table

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-table

I'd like to save the order in which the users of a simple HTML page click on the rows of the table (and also save the timestamp). For example, take this table

```
<table id="tableId">
<tr id="a">
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr id="c">
    <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then say the user clicks on row "a" first, then row "c", then row "a" again, then row "b".

I would like to save it to a simple CSV file, which would look like:

"a",7:29:32

"c",7:29:48

"a",7:30:12

"b",7:30:28

I have a feeling that the best would be to use JQuery and PhP, but I'm very new to these, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Balazs

Comment: No mention of how you intend to use the stored data. There are multiple ways it can be saved but where and how you actually save it depends on use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach to exporting the cell ID & timestamp to a CSV file might be to use a `Blob`. The table row/cell clicks populate a global variable called `store` - the order in the array is the order in which they were clicked. When the user wishes to save this data click the `save` button to generate the Blob which is presented to the user as file download courtesy of `URL.createObjectURL` and the `download` attribute for the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            table{width:80%;}
            tr{cursor:pointer;width:100%;padding:0.5rem}
            tr:hover{background:pink}
            tr:active{background:yellow}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tableId">
          <tr id="a">
              <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="b">
              <td>b</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="c">
              <td>c</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <input type='button' value='Save' />
        
        
        <script>
        
            let store=[];
            let args={ hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit' };

            document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr=>tr.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                store.push([ 
                    JSON.stringify( this.id ),
                    JSON.stringify( new Date().toLocaleTimeString( 'en-GB', args ) ) 
                ]);
            }));


            document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){
                let blob=new Blob( [ store ], { type:'text/csv' } );
                let a=document.createElement('a');
                    a.download='export.csv';
                    a.href=URL.createObjectURL( blob );
                    a.click();
                  
                store=[];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do this with the help of event handlers. Here's a basic sampler to get you started.

In the event handler, you capture the target element's `id`, or any other information available. Add `console.log(this)` or `console.log(e.target)` (synonymous) to your code to understand what data is captured with a click event. Then generate a timestamp, and add the info to your log. Here we just dump the log at each event, you'd probably want to do something more.

```js
// Log click events into an array
let clickLog = [];

// Element for dumping out the log
let loggerElement = document.querySelector('#log');

// Log dumper (adapt for your use case)
function iterateLog() {
    loggerElement.innerHTML = ''; 
    
    for(const clickData of clickLog) {
        loggerElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `${clickData[0]}: ${clickData[1]}\n`);
    }
}

// Let's select all <td> elements:
let tdList = document.querySelectorAll('td');

// And then attach click event handlers:
for(const td of tdList) {
    td.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Logging: [ parentElement.id, timestamp ]
        clickLog.push([this.parentElement.id, new Date().valueOf()]);
        // And write it out right away, for purposes of this demo:
        iterateLog();
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="a"><td>alpha</td></tr>
<tr id="b"><td>beta</td></tr>
<tr id="g"><td>gamma</td></tr>
<tr id="d"><td>delta</td></tr>
</table>

<pre id="log"></pre>
```

You will not be able to *save* it as a CSV file directly from Javascript though. Either pass it with AJAX to a server-end PHP script for saving -- or provide a download on the fly, and save it yourself. (How to implement either of these options is beyond this post.)

Comment: OP is asking about order of rows clicked, not cells

Comment: @charlietfl oh yes correct. Available with `this.parentElement.id`. Updated the answer to match, with `<tr>` having the `id`. Figured it didn't make much difference, since there's just one cell per row in the question.

Comment: Would be a lot less event listeners if they were just on the rows themselves. Assuming only one cell per row is not practical for all use cases. Remember your answer is not only for the current OP but also others in the future as well